# Unsaved Transient Instance Hibernate

Tags: excel, hibernate, apache-poi, one-to-many

Although there are several questions related to this exception, Folks, this is not a possible duplicate . Iterating through multiple excel sheets using APACHE POI , I have to use JPA to perform a many to one relation

```
for (int i = 0; i < wb.getNumberOfSheets(); i++) {
            HSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(i);
      ....
   if(i=0)
{
   Baseclass obj = new Baseclass ();
   obj.setname("name");
   session.save(obj)
   session.getTransaction().commit();
} 

  if(i=3)
{
  Foreigclass obj2 = new Foreigclass ();
  obj2.setsection("2A");
  Baseclass obj = new Baseclass ();
 --> obj2.setTransport(obj); // linking foreign keys // error comes here
  session.save(obj2)
}
```

At the marked line, I am getting the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: model.CepTransport
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.ForeignKeys.getEntityIdentifierIfNotUnsaved(ForeignKeys.java:294)
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.getIdentifier(EntityType.java:537)
    at org.hibernate.type.ManyToOneType.isDirty(ManyToOneType.java:311)
    at org.hibernate.type.ManyToOneType.isDirty(ManyToOneType.java:321)
    at org.hibernate.type.TypeHelper.findDirty(TypeHelper.java:294)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.findDirty(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4243)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.dirtyCheck(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:546)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.isUpdateNecessary(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:232)
```

Can someone suggest what is wrong here ? The CASCADing properties are fine and everything works fine if data comes from only one excel sheet.

Comment: and what is the connection between a spreadsheet and Hibernate here? You read in the Spreadsheet then persist to an RDBMS using Hibernate?

Comment: Yes, the values are read from Excel and saved into a DB, using Hibernate

Comment: ok, FWIW you could easily enough read objects from Excel using DataNucleus JPA, that way have no need for a separate API usage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In below code you are creating objects for `Foreigclass` & `Baseclass` and trying to save only one:

```
Foreigclass obj2 = new Foreigclass (); // Created Foreigclass object
obj2.setsection("2A");
Baseclass obj = new Baseclass (); // Created Baseclass object
obj2.setTransport(obj); // linking foreign keys // error comes here
session.save(obj2);
```

So initially the `obj2` and `obj` are in Transient state, so when you call `session.save(obj2)` it checks the linked entities and there state before making `obj2` to Persistent state. As `obj` is still in Transient state it complains with error as:

```
org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance 
- save the transient instance before flushing: model.CepTransport.
```

Here I guess `CepTransport` is same as `Baseclass`.

To fix this issue, save your `Baseclass` before saving `Foreigclass` like this:

```
session.save(obj); 
session.save(obj2);
```

But if you want to use CASCADE setting then check the settings at `Foreigclass` and make sure that the CASCADE values are correct.

Comment: Can you explain further , what you mean by "save your Baseclass before saving Foreigclass" .. and how to do this ?

Comment: Thanks Chaitanya,  this removed the error. Thanks. But now you see that the foreignclass is instantiating the base class method and inserting empty rows into it !

Comment: @Abhinav, what do you mean by empty row? do you mean a new row is created having value only for primary key? If yes then your java code is doing like that, you just created Baseclass object and not setting any values for it and directly trying to save it using hibernate.